# while loop with strings only runs once

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am having a hard time trying to figure out what is wrong with this code. Can someone tell me what is wrong with this while loop? It will only run once.

```
i= input("Please enter I to report or enter Exit to exit. ")
while i.lower == "i":
    print("in loop")

    #to rerun code or exit it
    i = input("Please enter I to report  or enter Finish to exit. ")

print("done")
```

Comment: Are the missing parentheses in `i.lower` intentional? Isn't the number of loop iterations determined by the input, which you haven't specified? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `()` after your `lower` call. You're never actually calling the function to lowercase `i`.

```
while i.lower() == "i":

i.lower
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x0000018E4AC5A0F0>

i.lower == 'i'
False

i.lower()
'i'

i.lower() == 'i'
True
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but you need to type just i, not I.

```
i= input("Please enter I to report or enter to exit. ")
while i == "i":
    if i == "i":
        print("in loop")
        i = input("Please enter I to report  or enter to exit. ")
if i != "i" :
    print("done")
```

Comment: Why are you checking the state of `i` so many times? The while loop confirms the state every iteration, there is no need to check it 3 times.